# How to automatically log user in ionic 1 hybrid app?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, authorization

I want to move my angularJS web app to ionic hybrid app. I have done a lot of work all ready however I am confused on "autologin" topic. There are a lot of different information on internet, also the official docs are a bit unclear to me.

The scenario I am looking for is standart - on first lunch user creates account, logs in and next time he open app he is already logged in.

A lot of resources suggests to use localstorage. However there a some [threath](https://gonehybrid.com/dont-assume-localstorage-will-always-work-in-your-hybrid-app/) that it is not safe because IOs can clean localstorages.

So if that is not a good option, what is? Cookies?

I have spent hour reading and testing different approaches but well even more confused than ever. It seems to me as such important feature of hybrid app that there should be a good implementation... Would appreciate any help/suggestions/examples/links...

My ultimate goal would be that once authorized user can access and manipulate his profile data even if in offline mode. That means that opening app allready logs him in an his profile info is stored as well.

My minimum viable goal would be that when app is opened app recognizes user, checks as logged in, redirects to logged in state and makes http to get all user details. While user is waiting for that response there are loading spinners but he can start to use logged in app experience

Answer (score 0):

I am working in Cordova ionic app, where I have stored token in localstorage. But it's not a good process. Have a look at Google FIREBASE. They have a good solution for you.

Comment: Firebase is not an option, i need to have my own backend